# "x.[PropertyName] is not a function" in render map()?

Tags: reactjs

I'm adding a spacer tr after groups of related tr's in a React component.  I'm rendering the rows via a map() function.  I've added a property to the last item in the collection named IsLastItem.  I'm trying to prevent the map() function from writing out a spacer row after the last item in the collection by using a guard condition at the end of the map() like this:

```
              { y && {!y.IsLastItem} (
                <tr>
                  <td colSpan={4} style={{height:25}}></td>
                </tr>
              )}
```

However, the following runtime error is being thrown with this implementation:

> y.IsLastItem is not a function

I've validated that the IsLastItem property does exist on the last item in the collection.  Even if the IsLastItem property didn't exist on the last item, it seems like there shouldn't be any runtime errors since undefined would simply eval to false.  Any idea what I might be doing wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0):

You are using curly braces which are used for functions. That's why it is misleading that. You need to do it like:

```
{ y && y.IsLastItem && (
  <tr>
     <td colSpan={4} style={{height:25}}></td>
   </tr>
)}
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this:

```
{ y && !y.IsLastItem &&
  <tr>
    <td colSpan={4} style={{height:25}}></td>
  </tr>
}
```

or

```
{ y && !y.IsLastItem ? (
  <tr>
    <td colSpan={4} style={{height:25}}></td>
  </tr>
): null}
```

Best way is the 1st one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented the IsLastItem then you want

```
{ y && !y.IsLastItem (
  <tr>
    <td colSpan={4} style={{height:25}}></td>
  </tr>
)}
```

Otherwise probably

```
items.map(item, index) => {

{ y && index >= items.length (
  <tr>
    <td colSpan={4} style={{height:25}}></td>
  </tr>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in your conditional. You used curly braces to surround your conditional: `{!y.IsLastItem}`, which is not the correct syntax for conditionals, and that is causing it to try to execute the block inside as a function. Remove the curly braces and add another `&&` after the conditional before the block of code you want to return.

So it should be `y && y.IsLastItem && (whatever JSX you want to return if it's the last item)`

To only add the separator after the last item in the array of items, your `.map` statement might look something like this:

```
items.map(y => {
  return (
    <>

      ... # whatever your standard row component for y is

      {y && y.IsLastItem && (
        <tr>
          <td colSpan={4} style={{height:25}}></td>
        </tr>
      )}
    </>
  )
})
```